# Writing a MongoDB query to filter based on a reference's attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Let's say I have a set of documents called "dog," a set of documents called "owners," and a reference to an owner from within each dog document.

For example:

```
dog1:
{"_id": "abcdef0123456789",
 "name": "Rover",
 "owner": ObjectId("1234567890abcdef")}

owner1:
{"_id": "1234567890abcdef",
 "name": "Bob"}
```

So, given that example, how would I find all dogs whose owner is named "Bob."

This is an existing DB, so I can't change how it stores data. I'm stuck with the current format.

Comment: do you store _id as a string in collection owner?

Comment: @thev0id It's the ID assigned by Mongo when you create an object. So, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below  [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) aggregation in mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.owner.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "Bob" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "dogs",
    "let": { "ownerId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$owner", "$$ownerId"] }}}],
    "as": "dogs"
  }}
])
```

or with the **3.4** [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match) and above

```
db.owner.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "Bob" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "dogs",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "owner",
    "as": "dogs"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Does the 3.4 version still work with 3.6? Because that looks a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you?